# Excel - Auto increment value based on string search

Tags: excel

I've got a set of data that needs updating to use the same "reference" value (auto-incrementing by .1 with each record found) where a name matches against the first two words.

Please see below for an example table with the desired format required below - is there a way to do this via an automated function in Excel?

Alternatively, I can use SQL Server to do this if easier.

Many thanks in advance

| Name | Current Reference | DESIRED Reference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First Name | 1001.1 | 1001.1 |
| First Name Also | 2123.1 | 1001.2 |
| First Name Also With More Text | 3456.1 | 1001.3 |
| Second Name | 4567.1 | 4567.1 |
| Second Name Also | 1232.1 | 4567.2 |
| Second Name Also With More Text & Symbols | 5890.1 | 4567.3 |

Comment: How are the first 4 digits set?  Are you wanting to do this in the second column or is the second column part of the reference to get the first 4 digits, so the output would be in the third column?

Comment: Hi Scott, so I need to assign any matching names (preferably a CONTAINS search) in my list the same reference number (first 4 digits), incrementing each new record by .1 so that these can be grouped together. I'm not sure whether it's easier to do this on the data source itself via a SQL Query?